# How to get and display Json Array data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Hi I am beginner in ios in my project i have tried to get below Json Array data but it's showing exception(`like -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be53f80`) what did i do here wrong please help me, and here data is successfully loaded in my main `arrayList`

### my json formate:-

```
  final respone dictionary(
        {
        Name = " ";
        id = 0;
    },
        {
        Name = "PREMIER DIM OUT";
        id = 10;
    },
        {
        Name = "PRADO COLLECTION";
        id = 15;
    },
        {
        Name = "PURE WALLS 6";
        id = 16;
    },
        {
        Name = PLATINA;
        id = 17;
    },
        {
        Name = "SARMASIK LEATHER";
        id = 19;
    },
        {
        Name = "PICASA COLLECTION";
        id = 21;
    },
        {
        Name = "3PASS BLACK OUT-SLOT LOT";
        id = 25;
    },
        {
        Name = ABYSS;
        id = 26;
    },
        {
        Name = ABYSSION;
        id = 27;
    },
        {
        Name = "ACC BOOK MODERN ELEMENT 2";
        id = 28;
    },
        {
        Name = "ACCESSORIES ROUSES 342";
        id = 29;
    },
        {
        Name = ACE;
        id = 30;
    },
        {
        Name = "ACHILLES (PAZZION)";
        id = 31;
    }
  )  
    my code:-
    ------------

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

        NSString * allDataDictionbary = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSDictionary * responseString = [allDataDictionbary JSONValue];

      NSLog(@"final respone dictionary%@",responseString);

     NSMutableArray * mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         [mainArray addObject:responseString];

         for (int i = 0; i<mainArray.count; i++) {


                NSDictionary *BatchDict = [mainArray objectAtIndex:i];

                NSString * name = [BatchDict objectForKey:@"Name"];
                NSString * Id = [BatchDict objectForKey:@"id"];

                [NameArray addObject:name];
                [IdArray addObject:Id];
            }


            NSLog(@"so finally name array%@",NameArray);
            NSLog(@"so finally Id array%@",IdArray);
    }
```

Comment: What is your "mainDictyionary" ? Ramji please put some more code..

Comment: i have added mainDictinary in my mainArray

Comment: That is an array, not a Dictionary..

Comment: mainDictyionary is my response dictionary from services and i have added that in MutableArray(mainarray)

Comment: Please post your full response from top to bottom..

Comment: you mean what should i post?

Comment: NSLog of your server response (full text)

Comment: How you create your "mainDictyionary" object, that I want to know..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97410/discussion-between-abhiram-and-nspratik).

Answer (score 3):

You are making a mistake of taking an array as dictionary. You are adding an array into array and you are treating this added array as a dictionary.

You need to only enumerate through your JSON array object..

If still not getting, post the full response, I will help you !!!

Answer (score 2):

By seeing your JSON FROMAT.It is clear that is Array.So Please put your response json in to Array your other code is right.

Just Follow this

```
NSArray *jsonArray = YOUR_JSON_RESPONSE_AS_SHOWN_ABOVE
NSMutableArray * mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:jsonArray];

for (int i = 0; i<mainArray.count; i++) {


    NSDictionary *BatchDict = [mainArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString * name = [BatchDict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString * Ids = [BatchDict objectForKey:@"id"];

    [NameArray addObject:name];
    [IdArray addObject:Ids];
}

NSLog(@"so finally name array%@",NameArray);
NSLog(@"so finally Id array%@",IdArray);
```

It will work fine . . . .

Comment: Abhi use this. . .Jus put your above response in jsonArray object and run this code . . .

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to put `JSONdata` into dictionary.

For example like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                           options:kNilOptions 
                                                             error:&error];
```

where `data` is your JSON object, then you can simply use

```
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [dictionary description]);
```

Hope this will work for you.